# i have a sql table having three columns as city, yr2008, yr2009

Tags: sql

```
city yr2008 yr2009
M     100    170
p     200    100   
N     50     20
k     100    30
```

how to get following result with sql query.

```
city year
M     100
M     170
P     200
P     100
N     50 
N     20
K     100
K     30
```

Comment: What rdms are you using? (mysql,oracel,mssql)

Answer (score 3):

`Union` / `Union all` should do the job

```
select * 
from 
(
select city, yr2008 as year
from yourtable 
Union all
select city, yr2009 as year
from yourtable  
)a
order by city
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use union for this. Take a look at the sample below:

```
create table sample (
  city varchar(10),
  year2008 integer,
  year2009 integer
);


insert into sample values ('M', 100, 170);
insert into sample values ('P', 200, 100);



select combined_result.city, combined_result.year
FROM (
  select city, year2008 as year 
  from sample
  union 
  select city, year2009 as year
  from sample 
) as combined_result order by combined_result.city;
```

Comment: How is this any different from Milen Pavlovs answer?

Comment: There was no answer while I was typing the queries in SQL fiddle, after submission, I noticed it